# Is L-cysteine that is derived from human or animal sources halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

[L-cysteine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cysteine#Industrial_sources) is mostly made from human hair, chicken or duck feathers, boar bristles etc., or it can be synthetic. I would like to know if it is halal, since it can be found in many bakery products such as bread, pizza dough, bagels, donuts etc.

Comment: Do you want to edit the question to mean L-cysteine derived from animal sources? (those animals that are not halal for us to consume, either inherently or because of their manner of slaughter)

Comment: Yes, I meant the human/animal sources, and I've made the edit.

Comment: FYI, if the quantity is sufficiently small, it will not affect the halality of the product. Let me know if you want me to post an answer detailing this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is L-cysteine halal?

Yes, it is.

### What is L-cystiene?

Cysteine (abbreviated as Cys or C)[3] is an α-amino acid with the chemical formula HO2CCH(NH2)CH2SH. It is a semi-essential amino acid, which means that it can be biosynthesized in humans.
P.S Biosynthesized meansthe following - Biosynthesis (also called biogenesis) is an enzyme-catalyzed process in cells of living organisms by which substrates are converted to more complex products.
or **in brief it is produced in our body** (**this is one proof that it is halal**).Cysteine can usually be **synthesized by the human body** under normal physiological conditions if a sufficient quantity of methionine is available. Cysteine is catabolized in the gastrointestinal tract and blood plasma.

### Where is is used? Where is it found?

Although classified as a non-essential amino acid, in rare cases, **cysteine may be essential for infants, the elderly, and individuals** with certain metabolic disease or who suffer from malabsorption syndromes. (**2<sup>nd</sup> proof of being halal**)

Cysteine is found in most high-protein foods, including:

Animal sources:- Sausage meat, chicken, turkey, duck, luncheon meat, eggs, milk, whey protein, ricotta, cottage cheese, yogurt.

Plant sources:- Red peppers, garlic, onions, broccoli, brussels sprout, oats, granola, wheat germ. (**3<sup>rd</sup> proof of being halal.** As these food stuff are halal and they occur naturally in these foods then it has to be halal.)

**Note**- Im not a biology student so this information is not from me but from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cysteine).
Another thing to note is that L-cystiene is the same as cystiene. Well actually along with L-cystiene there also exists D-cystiene. They both are same to cystiene. Their chemical properties are similar but their physical properties might not be similar. i know this because i am a chemistry student.

Comment: Just because our body produces it doesn't mean it's a proof for being halal :) Our body produces lots of other things that are unlawful for consumption.

Comment: @Ansari i know you might be thinking of urine etc. but i meant that it is produced to be used as a nutrient

Comment: Point taken - but I suspect the question is more about the sources of the L-cysteine than the compound itself. I asked the OP to clarify.

Comment: @Ansari i think OP is confused between natural and man-made sources

Comment: Probably not confused, just forgot to clarify. Anyway let's just wait

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Most of the L-cysteine that is used in bakery products is either made from human hair or chicken/duck feathers etc. (http://www.naturalnews.com/032718_L-cysteine_commercial_bread.html) I just wanted to know what's the ruling of L-cysteine from these sources.

Answer (score 0):

Well muslim consumer group declares the following
The L-Cysteine made from human hair is a Haram ingredient. The L-Cystiene made from chicken/duck feathers is not consider as Halal by ulema. July 2014

Comment: It would be useful to add your resource here